# Red Hat Directory Server and 389 Directory Server, differences

Tags: redhat, ldap, fedora

Red Hat Directory Server and 389 Directory Server are the same product? Or what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 389 Directory Server is absolutely identical to the Red Hat Directory Server. It's the same product.

[It's just rebranded with Red Hat logos.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/389_Directory_Server)